# Tool to create HTML form using Java bean

Tags: java, html

I am trying to find a way to quickly generate HTML forms based on java code. Ideally I would paste the java bean into a tool which would generate the HTML form for me using the member field types and the validation annotations.

So if I paste

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 14)
private String plate;
```

into the tool it 
would generate

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="plate" id="plate"  minlength="2" maxlength="14"></input>
</form>
```

There must be something that can do this, surely everyone is not doing this manually but I cannot find anything to do it! Is there a tool I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://isis.apache.org/, maybe it's something for you.